# Saving presentation details kills browser

Tags: content-editor, presentation, templates

I'm having issue with saving presentation details on standard values for a template.

I navigate to the template and standard values I'd like to edit in content editor, I open presentation details window. Then I select rendering and, for example, clear data source.

I close the dialog for editing rendering with OK, and then I want to save the presentation details by pressing OK on the dialog.

The dialog freezes, and I can see in the browser network tab following which takes up to 25 minutes to finish:

`/sitecore/shell/applications/content-editor?ic=Apps%2F48x48%2FPencil.png&he=Content%20Editor&cl=0`

Payload of the request:

```
__RESULT:<container VersionCreated="false">
  <shared>
    <r xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}" l="{6706F848-B798-489F-9618-4D9946AEA084}">
        <p uid="{FA454E84-E5BD-4B42-A1D2-D523151058DC}" key="topicpromowidget" md="{8A1D784E-BEAC-4610-B613-7EE7A83B50C9}" />
        <r id="{F1F15125-4136-40BB-8B50-610CA907D9CC}" ph="searchbox" uid="{1E645B14-E9E4-4152-8BAB-2A1915A20EA1}" />
        <r id="{502314A7-612F-4492-B515-5B01807B2561}" ph="share" uid="{94675DB3-76AB-4AB0-8408-9C017C66B7FD}" />
        <r cac="1" id="{5E445455-51C2-4F75-8E19-6578A7A1BBAB}" ph="content" uid="{51A61C29-3146-4202-A4C9-1E626D20D8F8}" vbd="1" vbdev="1" />
        <r id="{D13BBEE4-23C3-45D8-8FC8-A02AEB3A262C}" ph="/header/h_search" uid="{91F7793F-0002-4902-B0F9-F25DDAD0C92B}" />
        <r ds="" id="{C328EB7C-CEC7-4987-980B-3718AD6EF607}" par="" ph="topicpromowidget" uid="{B0232425-2182-42F1-9421-05BDB9280C14}" />
      </d>
      <d id="{028EB522-0D24-4FCD-99C3-D1C752C599CE}" l="{6706F848-B798-489F-9618-4D9946AEA084}">
        <p uid="{FF4D593D-E10D-48C8-A3ED-DC8837B4F181}" key="topicpromowidget" md="{8A1D784E-BEAC-4610-B613-7EE7A83B50C9}" />
        <r id="{F1F15125-4136-40BB-8B50-610CA907D9CC}" ph="searchbox" uid="{1E645B14-E9E4-4152-8BAB-2A1915A20EA1}" />
        <r id="{502314A7-612F-4492-B515-5B01807B2561}" ph="share" uid="{D077AE36-86C4-4D45-81AB-667B54FAE9C1}" />
        <r cac="1" id="{5E445455-51C2-4F75-8E19-6578A7A1BBAB}" ph="content" uid="{51A61C29-3146-4202-A4C9-1E626D20D8F8}" vbd="1" vbdev="1" />
        <r id="{D13BBEE4-23C3-45D8-8FC8-A02AEB3A262C}" ph="/header/h_search" uid="{91F7793F-0002-4902-B0F9-F25DDAD0C92B}" />
        <r id="{C328EB7C-CEC7-4987-980B-3718AD6EF607}" ph="topicpromowidget" uid="{297799F1-8702-43DF-BB4B-6390A08E9294}" />
      </d>
      <d id="{74417593-C3E0-42C4-9CBC-767F4158DEC1}" l="{6706F848-B798-489F-9618-4D9946AEA084}">
        <p uid="{C04E5649-6A57-4764-8B7F-B0F411CEFFA4}" key="topicpromowidget" md="{8A1D784E-BEAC-4610-B613-7EE7A83B50C9}" />
        <r id="{F1F15125-4136-40BB-8B50-610CA907D9CC}" ph="searchbox" uid="{1E645B14-E9E4-4152-8BAB-2A1915A20EA1}" />
        <r id="{502314A7-612F-4492-B515-5B01807B2561}" ph="share" uid="{D077AE36-86C4-4D45-81AB-667B54FAE9C1}" />
        <r cac="1" id="{5E445455-51C2-4F75-8E19-6578A7A1BBAB}" ph="content" uid="{51A61C29-3146-4202-A4C9-1E626D20D8F8}" vbd="1" vbdev="1" />
        <r id="{D13BBEE4-23C3-45D8-8FC8-A02AEB3A262C}" ph="/header/h_search" uid="{91F7793F-0002-4902-B0F9-F25DDAD0C92B}" />
        <r id="{C328EB7C-CEC7-4987-980B-3718AD6EF607}" ph="topicpromowidget" uid="{9C9D780F-38A3-4253-8A7B-DA6D41CE8C22}" />
      </d>
    </r>
  </shared>
  <final>
    <r xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}" l="{6706F848-B798-489F-9618-4D9946AEA084}">
        <p uid="{FA454E84-E5BD-4B42-A1D2-D523151058DC}" key="topicpromowidget" md="{8A1D784E-BEAC-4610-B613-7EE7A83B50C9}" />
        <r id="{F1F15125-4136-40BB-8B50-610CA907D9CC}" ph="searchbox" uid="{1E645B14-E9E4-4152-8BAB-2A1915A20EA1}" />
        <r id="{502314A7-612F-4492-B515-5B01807B2561}" ph="share" uid="{94675DB3-76AB-4AB0-8408-9C017C66B7FD}" />
        <r cac="1" id="{5E445455-51C2-4F75-8E19-6578A7A1BBAB}" ph="content" uid="{51A61C29-3146-4202-A4C9-1E626D20D8F8}" vbd="1" vbdev="1" />
        <r id="{D13BBEE4-23C3-45D8-8FC8-A02AEB3A262C}" ph="/header/h_search" uid="{91F7793F-0002-4902-B0F9-F25DDAD0C92B}" />
        <r ds="" id="{C328EB7C-CEC7-4987-980B-3718AD6EF607}" par="" ph="topicpromowidget" uid="{B0232425-2182-42F1-9421-05BDB9280C14}" />
      </d>
      <d id="{028EB522-0D24-4FCD-99C3-D1C752C599CE}" l="{6706F848-B798-489F-9618-4D9946AEA084}">
        <p uid="{FF4D593D-E10D-48C8-A3ED-DC8837B4F181}" key="topicpromowidget" md="{8A1D784E-BEAC-4610-B613-7EE7A83B50C9}" />
        <r id="{F1F15125-4136-40BB-8B50-610CA907D9CC}" ph="searchbox" uid="{1E645B14-E9E4-4152-8BAB-2A1915A20EA1}" />
        <r id="{502314A7-612F-4492-B515-5B01807B2561}" ph="share" uid="{D077AE36-86C4-4D45-81AB-667B54FAE9C1}" />
        <r cac="1" id="{5E445455-51C2-4F75-8E19-6578A7A1BBAB}" ph="content" uid="{51A61C29-3146-4202-A4C9-1E626D20D8F8}" vbd="1" vbdev="1" />
        <r id="{D13BBEE4-23C3-45D8-8FC8-A02AEB3A262C}" ph="/header/h_search" uid="{91F7793F-0002-4902-B0F9-F25DDAD0C92B}" />
        <r id="{C328EB7C-CEC7-4987-980B-3718AD6EF607}" ph="topicpromowidget" uid="{297799F1-8702-43DF-BB4B-6390A08E9294}" />
      </d>
      <d id="{74417593-C3E0-42C4-9CBC-767F4158DEC1}" l="{6706F848-B798-489F-9618-4D9946AEA084}">
        <p uid="{C04E5649-6A57-4764-8B7F-B0F411CEFFA4}" key="topicpromowidget" md="{8A1D784E-BEAC-4610-B613-7EE7A83B50C9}" />
        <r id="{F1F15125-4136-40BB-8B50-610CA907D9CC}" ph="searchbox" uid="{1E645B14-E9E4-4152-8BAB-2A1915A20EA1}" />
        <r id="{502314A7-612F-4492-B515-5B01807B2561}" ph="share" uid="{D077AE36-86C4-4D45-81AB-667B54FAE9C1}" />
        <r cac="1" id="{5E445455-51C2-4F75-8E19-6578A7A1BBAB}" ph="content" uid="{51A61C29-3146-4202-A4C9-1E626D20D8F8}" vbd="1" vbdev="1" />
        <r id="{D13BBEE4-23C3-45D8-8FC8-A02AEB3A262C}" ph="/header/h_search" uid="{91F7793F-0002-4902-B0F9-F25DDAD0C92B}" />
        <r id="{C328EB7C-CEC7-4987-980B-3718AD6EF607}" ph="topicpromowidget" uid="{9C9D780F-38A3-4253-8A7B-DA6D41CE8C22}" />
      </d>
    </r>
  </final>
</container>
__PIPELINE:512B876B25B84100B86C1D63DCDCD330
__CSRFTOKEN:/wEFJDA0YzVkMmZhLWQ3NDUtNDZjOS04ZDc3LWMyNTc1ZDdmMjUzMg==
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__VIEWSTATE:5324B75A07C6415C98F56D7369376B5B
__VIEWSTATE:
scLanguage:en
RadSpell:
RadSpell_dialogOpener_Window_ClientState:
RadSpell_dialogOpener_ClientState:
RadSpell_ClientState:
scActiveRibbonStrip:Ribbon1B9C0A8E346644E1BCB89B52F8BD3A4B_Strip_PresentationStrip
scEditorTabs:
scActiveEditorTab:
scPostAction:
scShowEditor:1
scSections:
scGalleries:
TreeSearch:{1B9C0A8E-3466-44E1-BCB8-9B52F8BD3A4B}
SearchOptionsValue0:
SearchOptionsName0:_name
SearchOptionsAddCriteria:Field
ToolTipManager1B9C0A8E346644E1BCB89B52F8BD3A4B_ClientState:
FIELD544763151:
FIELD544763154:
FIELD544763156:
FIELD544763157:
FIELD544763166:
FIELD544763167_Value:
FIELD544763168:
FIELD544763169:
FIELD544763171:
FIELD544763172:
FIELD544763173:
FIELD544763174:
FIELD544763175:
FIELD544763176:
FIELD544763177:
FIELD544763180:
FIELD544763182:
FIELD544763183:
FIELD544763184:
FIELD544763185:
FIELD544763186:
FIELD544763187:
FIELD544763188:
FIELD544763189:
FIELD544763190:
FIELD544763191:
FIELD544763192:
FIELD544763193:
FIELD544763194:1
FIELD544763196:
FIELD544763198:
FIELD544763199:
FIELD544763200:
FIELD544763203:
FIELD544763205:
FIELD544763206:
FIELD544763207:0
FIELD544763208:
FIELD544763210:
FIELD544763211:
FIELD544763212:
FIELD544763213:
FIELD544763215:
FIELD544763216:
FIELD544763218_all_Selected:0B42DC055CF94DD59A3A8BDF11BE2B88
FIELD544763218_all_Database:master
FIELD544763218_all_Parameters:?dv=Master&fi
FIELD544763218_all_Language:en
FIELD544763221:
FIELD544763225:
FIELD544763226:
FIELD544763227_Value:
FIELD544763229_Value:
FIELD544763233:
FIELD544763234:
FIELD544763235_all_Selected:D25A8DEA1AA0453788C607E6388E22D3
FIELD544763235_all_Database:master
FIELD544763235_all_Parameters:?dv=Master&fi
FIELD544763235_all_Language:en
FIELD544763236:
FIELD544763237:
FIELD544763238_picker_date:
FIELD544763238_picker_time:
FIELD544763239_picker_date:
FIELD544763239_picker_time:
FIELD544763241_picker_date:
FIELD544763241_picker_time:
FIELD544763242_picker_date:
FIELD544763242_picker_time:
FIELD544763245:sitecore\admin
FIELD544763247_picker_date:10/3/2014
FIELD544763247_picker_time:3:38 PM
FIELD544763248:sitecore\admin
FIELD544763249:f7882b25-d5d6-4cbe-8046-cb89d2ee54e4
FIELD544763250_picker_date:9/26/2017
FIELD544763250_picker_time:6:48 PM
FIELD544763251:sitecore\jczopek
FIELD544763252_Value:
filterBoxFIELD544763252:Type here to search
FIELD544763253_picker_date:
FIELD544763253_picker_time:
FIELD544763254_picker_date:
FIELD544763254_picker_time:
FIELD544763255_picker_date:
FIELD544763255_picker_time:
FIELD544763256:
FIELD544763263:
FIELD544763264:
FIELD544763266:Workflows/Worklfow
__CurrentItem:sitecore://master/{1B9C0A8E-3466-44E1-BCB8-9B52F8BD3A4B}?lang=en&ver=1
__PrimaryItem:sitecore://master/{1B9C0A8E-3466-44E1-BCB8-9B52F8BD3A4B}?lang=en&ver=1
scValidatorsKey:VK_96473FB95AC04FE5BFF8D4AC05A22FFA
scValidatorsUpdateDelay:750
__FRAMENAME:CE_D5189FB8843E4CB38A630A2CB312A910
scHasValidators:1
FIELD544763158:
FIELD544763159:
FIELD544763160:
FIELD544763161:
FIELD544763162:
FIELD544763163:
FIELD544763164:
FIELD544763165:
FIELD544763170:
FIELD544763179:
FIELD544763214:
FIELD544763232:
FIELD544763257:
FIELD544763262:
FIELD544763265:<r />
FIELD544763152:
FIELD544763155:
FIELD544763178:
FIELD544763150:All
FIELD544763181:Topic
FIELD544763209:{C1FF011E-B02A-44E3-8444-9FC89CFC28CE}
```

Does sitecore go over all items based on the template that I'm editing presentation details for? Is there way to improve it's performance?

### EDIT 1:

While running another test, I'm looking on performance and I can see high utilization of disk by SQL server. I suspect Sitecore might be going through all the items that use specific temaplate - in our particular case it's around 6k items in english language.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your log file while this is going on?

Comment: I see this, but I have doubts if that's related:
`4756 19:29:49 ERROR There is no appropriate index for /sitecore/templates - {3C1715FE-6A13-4FCF-845F-DE308BA9741D}. You have to add an index crawler that will cover this item
URL: sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/Services/Search.ashx
Referrer: sitecore/shell/applications/content-editor?ic=Apps%2F48x48%2FPencil.png&he=Content%20Editor&cl=0 (sitecore\jczopek)
`

Comment: Have you changed any of the default index configs, specifically the `<root>` node of the master index?

Comment: Yep, we have changed this. Now I have added crawler specifically for /sitecore/templates, reindex master buy it didn't help.